# При отправке формы - выдаёт ошибку 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, forms

html c формой:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Форма приветствия</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="open_gates.php" method="post">
<input value="Имя" width="50" type="text" id="Name" >
    <br>
<input value="Фамилия" width="50" type="text" id="FamilyName" >
    <br>
<input value="Отчество" width="50" type="text" id="Surname" >
    <br>
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Done">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

файл получатель open_gates.php

```php
<?
$N = $_POST['Name'];
$F = $_POST['FamilyName'];
$O = $_POST['Surname'];
echo "Добро пожаловать,". $F ." ". $N . " " . $O . ".";
```

Установлен IIS, не знаю, важно это или нет, cпасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В инпутах тэгах замени `id` на `name`.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли. Заработало